# Local dir that match the content of an external dir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like that when I call http://gamempire.localhost.it/data/ (that is a local path), it reads all the contents inside http://www.gamempire.it/data/

Example:
http://gamempire.localhost.it/data/thumbs/9/8/7/5/4/53c68aaa8f2e36502b34730ad5244903.jpg --> http://www.gamempire.it/data/thumbs/9/8/7/5/4/53c68aaa8f2e36502b34730ad5244903.jpg

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^data/(.*)$ http://www.gamempire.it/data/$1 [L]
```